# MySQL uses INDEX for optimizing ORDER BY with GROUP BY except when you add a JOIN

Tags: index, join, mysql-5.7, order-by

### Question

Why can't **Query #2** use the same `(car_trims.horsepower_peak)` index to optimize the sorting of the rows as **Query #1**? The **only** difference between the two queries is the addition of the `JOIN` in Query #2.

### car_trims ~50k rows

PK: `(car_trims.id)`, index on `(car_trims.horsepower_peak)`

### car_makes ~100 rows

PK: `(car_makes.id)`

**Query #1**

```
SELECT car_trims.*
FROM car_trims
GROUP BY car_trims.id
ORDER BY car_trims.horsepower_peak DESC
LIMIT 0, 200
```

Execution time: `.0026 seconds`

EXPLAIN:
[image: Query #1 EXPLAIN]

**Query #2**

```
SELECT car_trims.*
FROM car_trims
STRAIGHT_JOIN car_makes ON car_makes.id = car_trims.make_id
GROUP BY car_trims.id
ORDER BY car_trims.horsepower_peak DESC
LIMIT 0, 200
```

Execution time: `.2533 seconds`

EXPLAIN:
[image]

**UPDATE:**

I've been continuing to work on this and I believe the index is not being utilized in **Query #2** because of the mixing of `GROUP BY` and `ORDER BY`. According to the MySQL Docs,

> "In some cases, MySQL **cannot** use indexes to resolve the ORDER BY ...
>   [for example, when] ... the query has **different** `ORDER BY` and `GROUP BY`
>   expressions."

**Query #1** does mix `GROUP BY` and `ORDER BY` and so theoretically the index should not be used according to the docs but I believe that may not apply if the `GROUP BY` is being ignored entirely due to only 1 table being selected from and grouping on the primary key.

Also, my actual original query is not quite as simple as the example provided here. The crucial difference: usage of `GROUP_CONCAT` in the `SELECT` requiring the aforementioned `GROUP BY` in order to prevent grouping on all rows (i.e. getting a 1-row result). The solution to that issue is using a `DEPENDENT SUBQUERY`, as discussed here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7381828/indexing-with-group-by-order-by-and-group-concat

Comment: Firstly, please don't use [screenshots](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/470530) - use formatted text instead. Secondly, could you give us the output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE blah` for your tables. Have you tried without `STRAIGHT_JOIN`?

Comment: So I've been continuing to work on this and I believe it's because of the mixing of `GROUP BY` and `ORDER BY`. According to the MySQL Docs, "In some cases, MySQL cannot use indexes to resolve the ORDER BY ... [for example, when] ... the query has different ORDER BY and GROUP BY expressions."

Comment: My actual original query is not nearly as simple as the example provided. The crucial difference: usage of `GROUP_CONCAT` in the `SELECT` requiring the aforementioned `GROUP BY` in order to prevent grouping on all rows (i.e. getting a 1-row result). The solution to that issue is using a `DEPENDENT SUBQUERY`, as discussed here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7381828/indexing-with-group-by-order-by-and-group-concat

Comment: Addendum: Query #1 does mix `GROUP BY` and `ORDER BY` and so theoretically the index should not be used according to the docs but I believe that does not apply because the `GROUP BY` is being ignored due to only 1 table being selected from

Comment: Could you put extra/new information into the question using the edit option - makes life much easier for those trying to help.

Comment: When you want assistance, please post the 'real query', show create table tbl_name, EXPLAIN ...., etc. you need help with - to avoid secondary postings and wasted time for everyone.

Answer (score 1):

Query 1:  Since `id` is the `PRIMARY KEY`, it is unique.  Hence the `GROUP BY id` does nothing.  Remove it.  This may make it run faster.

Query 2 does not use any columns other than `id` from `car_makes`.  The only thing that the `JOIN` does is to verify that there is a row in `car_makes for the` make_id`.  You probably don't need that check, so get rid of` car_makes`in that query.  That will simplify things.  Note that currently there is a "filesort".  Without`car_makes`, that step will probably go away.

As for "why can't it use the same index" -- The `STRAIGHT_JOIN` forces it to look at the other table first.  This effectively turns the second table into

```
WHERE     make_id = ...
GROUP BY  id
ORDER BY  horsepower_peak DESC
```

To optimize such, it *must* first filter on `make_id`.

Comment: (I added an answer to your first question.)

Comment: I thought the point of the `STRAIGHT_JOIN` was to force the optimizer to look at the left table first?

Comment: @Dan - Yes, that is the point of `STRAIGHT_JOIN`.  But that is preventing it from using the _given_ index on `trims`.  For that query, it would be better to find the 200 rows, _then_ `JOIN`; `STRAIGHT_JOIN` prevents such.  Look at "Rows" in the two `EXPLAINs`.

Comment: As in create a temporary table using Query #1 and then joining `car_makes` on that temporary table to get the result set that I want? (Again, ultimately I want to be able to get `GROUP_CONCAT` values from `car_makes`)

Comment: Group_concat?  That will require a separate analysis.  Start another Question, show a short sample of data, plus the desired output.  (And repeat the CREATE TABLEs)